# scripting ipython through django's shell_plus

Tags: linux, django, shell, ipython

I'm writing a shell script which runs a command through ipython with the -c option like this:

```
ipython -c "from blah import myfunct; myfunct()"
```

but I want to invoke ipython through django's shell_plus command so I can take advantage of all the stuff shell_plus automatically loads for me:

```
$ ./manage.py shell_plus
```

I can't just add "-c ..." to the end of that because manage.py doesn't know what to do with it. Is there any way to pipe the -c option somehow?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1. Modify manage.py and add the -c option and remove it from sys.argv after processing
2. Modify manage.py and monkeypatch shell_plus so it supports -c by default
3. Put your code in some file and call `'PYTHONSTARTUP=your_file ./manage.py shell_plus'`

Comment: Note: Django checks to see if `PYTHONSTARTUP` is a file with `os.path.isfile(pythonrc)`, which means that it will not expand the path. So if your `PYTHONSTARTUP` starts with `~` it will not be imported