# Running profile startup files in an embedded IPython instance

Tags: python, django, ipython

I want to use an embedded IPython shell with a user_ns dictionary and a my profile configuration (ipython_config.py and the startup files). The purpose is to run a Django shell with models imported on startup. django-extensions implements a command called shell_plus that does this:

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py

```
from IPython import embed
embed(user_ns=imported_objects)
```

The problem is that this does not load my startup files. embed() calls load_default_config() which I figure loads ipython_config.py.

How do I make the embedded IPython instance run my profile startup files?

Comment: The same happens with `manage.py shell`, startup files aren't executed. Hope they'll fixed this soon. (ps, v 0.13)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following workaround to run my own IPython startup script but still take advantage of shell_plus:

1. Create a file called `shell_plus_startup.py` in the same directory as `manage.py`. For example:

   ```
   # File: shell_plus_startup.py
   # Extra python code to run after shell_plus starts an embedded IPython shell.
   # Run this file from IPython using '%run shell_plus_startup.py'

   # Common imports
   from datetime import date

   # Common variables
   tod = date.today()
   ```
2. Launch shell plus (which launches an embedded IPython shell).

   `python manage.py shell_plus`
3. Manually run the startup script.

   ```
   In [1]: %run shell_plus_startup.py
   ```
4. Then you can use variables you've defined, modules you've imported, etc.

   ```
   In [2]: tod
   Out[2]: datetime.date(2012, 7, 14)
   ```

Also see this answer: [scripting ipython through django's shell_plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266702/scripting-ipython-through-djangos-shell-plus?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that works if you are using django-extensions-shell_plus. It is a bit hacky, but with this way your startup file is loaded fully automatically and you don't have to type any run-command at the beginning of your ipython-session.

Therefore I edited the file `shells.py` from the django_extensions dir, which is in my case located in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_extensions/management/shells.py`. I added these lines inside the function `import_objects(options, style):`, so it imports the content of the file `startup.py` defined by the environment param `PYTHONSTARTUP`.

```
def import_objects(options, style):
    # (...)
    import os, sys, pkgutil
    if 'PYTHONSTARTUP' in os.environ:
        try:
            sys.path.append(os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP'])
            import startup
            content = [element for element in dir(startup) if not element.startswith('__')]
            for element in content:
                imported_objects[element] = getattr(startup, element)
        except Exception, ex:
            sys.exit("Could not import startup module content, Error:\n%s" % ex)
```

Now when I launch the shell_plus-shell, I give it the environment variable to my startup python script. My bash script to launch the shell with everything in place looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/ifischer/src/myproject/startup.py # tells shell_plus to load this file
python /home/ifischer/src/myproject/manage.py shell_plus --ipython
```

Now I have access to all methods and variables defined in startup.py from the beginning of the ipython session.

So you can reuse that and have custom startup files for every project, pre-loading different aspects.

Maybe there is a cleaner way where to include the lines I added to the shells.py? But this approach works fine for me for now.

Comment: I pushed the changes above into my fork of django-extensions: https://github.com/ifischer/django-extensions

Answer (score 0):

It does automatically load your ipython configuration starting from `django-extensions==1.5.6`. You can also pass additional arguments to `ipython` via IPYTHON_ARGUMENTS. Docs:
http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shell_plus.html#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using a class that derives from `InteractiveShellEmbed` and `InteractiveShellApp`. Sample, incomplete code:

```
from IPython.terminal.embed import InteractiveShellEmbed
from IPython.terminal.ipapp import InteractiveShellApp


class ISE(InteractiveShellEmbed, InteractiveShellApp):
    def init_shell(self):
        self.shell = self.instance()
        self.extra_args = []

ise = ISE()
ise.init_path()
ise.init_shell()
ise.init_code()
ise.shell()
```